# How to get session value in code file while session is created in httphandler

Tags: asp.net

How to get session value in code file while session is created in httphandler .it gives error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: If it isn't there, then you can not get it.

Answer (score 0):

The session is connected with a page request, to work is require to read the cookie of the user from the browser, or the url in case that is with out cookies.

So in the asp.net session if you do not have the httphandler, you can not have the session, because you can not know who is calling and see the page at that time.

Maybe in a custom solution session, you can send the session id to some other code with out the httphandler and use that id to read the session data, but the asp.net did not give this option.